# What conditions allow one rational sequence to bound another?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_k)$ and $(b_k)$ be infinite sequences of rational numbers with the following properties.

- For every $k$, $0 \le a_k \le 1$ and $0 \le b_k \le 1$.
- $a_k$ and $b_k$ are positive infinitely often.
- $\sum a_k \lt 1$, and that sum is irrational.
- $\sum b_k = 1.$
- $(a_k)$ has a known formula for each $a_k$, and $(b_k)$ is to be determined.

Then:

1. What conditions ensure that $a_k$ is bounded above by $b_k$ for every $k$?  In other words, given a formula for $(a_k)$, how can $(b_k)$ be built so that $0\le a_k \le b_k \le 1$ for every $k$?
2. What additional conditions ensure that $a_k$ is bounded above by $b_k$ for every $k$, when—

   - $(a_k)$ is known to be eventually decreasing, or
   - $(b_k)$ is built to be (eventually) geometrically decreasing, or
   - any combination of these?

For example, if $a_k$ is $1/k!$ if $k\ge 2$ and $k$ is even, and 0 otherwise (these are the coefficients of the Taylor series for $\cosh(x)-1$), then $(b_k)$ can be built as $1/(2^{(n-2)/2+1})$ if $k\ge 2$ and $k$ is even, and 0 otherwise.  For a different sequence of $(a_k)$, a different sequence of $(b_k)$ has to be built, and so on (e.g, different $(b_k)$ sequences for the Taylor coefficients of $\exp(x/4)/2$, $\sinh(x)/2$, and $\cosh(x)/2$), thus making it hard to determine whether a given sequence will work.

**Motivation:**

In my scenario:

- $(b_k)$ is a probability distribution (that is, $b_k$ is the probability of getting $k$).
- $\lambda$ is the probability that a biased coin shows heads.
- $f(\lambda) = \sum_{k\ge 0} a_k \lambda^k$ is a known function.

Then by sampling $X$ from the distribution $(b_k)$ and flipping a coin with probability of heads $\frac{a_X}{b_X} \lambda^X$, we can thus "flip" a new coin whose probability of heads is $f(\lambda)$ — without estimating the probability $\lambda$ directly (a convex combination according to Wästlund, J., "Functions arising by coin flipping", 1999, or one kind of *Bernoulli factory*, see Keane and O'Brien, "A Bernoulli factory", 1994). But this only works if, among other things, $a_k$ is bounded above by $b_k$ for every $k$ (in other words, the sequence $(a_k)$ can be "tucked" under the probabilities of the discrete distribution, represented by $(b_k)$), and this condition is not always easy to verify.

An example given earlier shows how to form $(a_k)$ and $(b_k)$ in order to turn a "$\lambda$ coin" into a "$(\cosh(\lambda)-1)$ coin" this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write $d=1-\sum a_k$ in its decimal expansion as $\sum c_k10^{-k}$ then you can let

$$b_k=a_k+c_k10^{-k}$$

and you get

$$\sum b_k=1$$
$$a_k\le b_k$$
$$b_k\in \mathbb{Q}$$

Comment: That is amazing.  Obviously, 10 can be replaced with 2 or any other base.

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: One thing to note is that you don't necessarily have $b_k>0$ infinitely often. For instance, if $a_1=0$ and $a_k=9\cdot 10^{-k}$ for $k>1$, then $b_1=9\times 10^{-1}$ and $b_k=0$ for all $k>1$. So, in this case $b_k$ is only positive for one $k$.

Comment: In your example, $\sum a_k = 1/10$, which is _rational_, which doesn't satisfy the hypothesis of my question.

Comment: Good point, I missed that.